# Responisve menu doestn work in Vue- dont understand my the plain JS doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```
<template>
  <header class="bg-white">
    <nav class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto">
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5968/5968204.png"
          alt="..."
          class="w-16"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        class="nav-links md:static md:min-h-fit absolute bg-green-300 min-h-[60vh] left-0 top-[-100%] w-full flex items-center md:w-auto px-5"
      >
        <ul
          class="flex md:flex-row flex-col md:items-center md:gap-[4vw] gap-8"
        >
          <li><a class="hover:text-gray-500" href="">Product</a></li>
          <li><a class="hover:text-gray-500" href="">About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="hover:text-gray-500" href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center gap-6">
        <button
          @click="toggleMenu"
          class="bg-[#a6c1ee] text-white px-5 py-2 rounded-full"
        >
          Sign in
        </button>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-width="1.5"
          stroke="currentColor"
          class="w-6 h-6 text-3-xl cursor-pointer md:hidden"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M3.75 5.25h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5m-16.5 4.5h16.5"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    toggleMenu() {
      const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      navLinks.classList.toggle("top-[9%]");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

I was making a responsove menu, and i dont understand why the toggle method doesnt work. At small screens, the hamburger menu doesnt work when clicked on button, but console log does work; nothing in the console as well. Seems pretty easy to make and it suprises me that result is bad...

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean?  Please be specific.  What is the expected vs actual result?  From what I can tell, all the method does is add the class name "top-[9%]".  Did you inspect the DOM? Does the class name not get added? using `document` interface is not recommended, but it should technically still work... query selecting and classList toggling is not necessary in Vue because [class binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) exists and is superior because it leaves control of the DOM in Vue's hands.

Comment: hey, thanku you for your response sir. Can you prove me more detail how to implement this function in Vue way?